# Associated enum represented as String and CGFloat for custom font?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to make it easy to use my custom font by using an enum. I need that associated enum to be represented as a `String` and a `CGFloat`, but finding it to be too redundant.

I want to end up with something like this:

```
Text("Some text here")
    .font(.acme(.regular(18), relativeTo: .headline))
```

To achieve this, this is my custom static font:

```
extension Font {
    
    static func acme(_ style: AcmeStyle, relativeTo textStyle: TextStyle) -> Self {
        .custom("\(style)", size: style.size, relativeTo: textStyle)
    }

    enum AcmeStyle {
        case regular(CGFloat)
        case light(CGFloat)
        case lightItalic(CGFloat)
        case bold(CGFloat)
        case boldItalic(CGFloat)
        case headline(CGFloat)
        case italic(CGFloat)
    }
}

extension Font.AcmeStyle: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .regular:
            return "AcmeApp-Regular"
        case .light:
            return "AcmeApp-Light"
        case .lightItalic:
            return "AcmeApp-LightItalic"
        case .bold:
            return "AcmeApp-Bold"
        case .boldItalic:
            return "AcmeApp-BoldItalic"
        case .headline:
            return "AcmeApp-Headline"
        case .italic:
            return "AcmeApp-Italic"
        }
    }

    var size: CGFloat {
        switch self {
        case let .regular(size):
            return size
        case let .light(size):
            return size
        case let .lightItalic(size):
            return size
        case let .bold(size):
            return size
        case let .boldItalic(size):
            return size
        case let .headline(size):
            return size
        case let .italic(size):
            return size
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without all the switch statements or a better API to handle what's trying to be achieved? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the associated value and add a size parameter?

Comment: I would change the method signature to `static func acme(_ style: Style, size: CGFloat, relativeTo textStyle: TextStyle) -> Self {` `.custom("\(style)", size: size, relativeTo: textStyle)` `}`

Comment: ant the enumeration to `enum Style: String, CustomStringConvertible {` `case regular, light, lightItalic, bold, boldItalic, headline, italic = "legal"` `var description: String {` `"AcmeApp-" + rawValue.capitalized }` `}`

Comment: You can also create a struct with your enumeration and a size property.